# Are there any cases when I should use the in operator instead of hasOwnProperty()?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, hasownproperty, ecmascript-2016

In JavaScript the `in` operator checks whether an object has the specified property. However, it doesn't check only object's own properties, but also the prototype chain. Therefore in some situations it may behave not exactly as expected.

Let's say that for some reason we have an object `someArrayMethods` containing (obviously) some array methods as keys:

```
const someArrayMethods = {
  indexOf: true,
  map: true,
};
```

We can check if that object has a specific method as a key using the `in` operator:

```
console.log('indexOf' in someArrayMethods); // true
console.log('every' in someArrayMethods); // false
```

What if we tried to check for `toString` property?

```
console.log('toString' in someArrayMethods); // true
```

Surprise! It turns out that this object has a [`toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) in the prototype chain, so the `in` operator returns `true` even though the object doesn't have its own `toString` property.

And here's where [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) comes to the rescue! It's almost the same as the `in` operator, with one difference: it doesn't check the prototype chain. We can rewrite our previous example:

```
console.log(someArrayMethods.hasOwnProperty('toString'));  // false
```

Now it works as expected. Unfortunately, `hasOwnProperty()` also can fail in one case. What if we had an object with an own property `hasOwnProperty`? See this example:

```
const someObject = {
  hasOwnProperty() {
    return false;
  },
  theAnswer: 42,
};

// Does `someObject` has own property `theAnswer`?
console.log(someObject.hasOwnProperty('theAnswer')); // false
// Well, it seems it doesn't...
```

To solve this problem, instead of using `someObject.hasOwnProperty`, we can refer to that method directly from `Object.prototype`:

```
const hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
console.log(hasOwn.call(someObject, 'theAnswer')); // true
```

This seems to be the most reasonable approach for checking if an object has some property. Despite this, **are there any cases where the `in` operator would be useful**? I know that it can be used to check if an instance of some class has some method, but in this case isn't it better to simply check if that object is an instance of that class?

---

As a side note, another option is to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with ECMAScript 2016 [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
console.log(Object.keys(someObject).includes('theAnswer')); // true
```

Comment: In most cases if a function accepts something with some property - it should not be its business where in the prototype chain the property is defined, but that it's just available. That way you separate the data shape from the implementation details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature detection for loading polyfills, testing conditions for using modern DOM APIs etc.

Using the `in` operator is ideal for assessing whether you should load/execute a JavaScript polyfill precisely because it checks the prototype chain.

For instance:

```
// this works wonderfully
if (!('addEventListener' in window)) {
  // polyfill addEventListener
}
```

compared to:

```
// this doesn't work at all
if (!window.hasOwnProperty('addEventListener')) {
  // polyfill addEventListener
}
```

Hence why [the Polyfill.io service](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/contributing/authoring-polyfills#detects) uses it for its feature detection tests.

Answer (score 5):

`in` is an operator, so it can't be hijacked. You don't have to rely on that no script altered or shadowed `Object`, `Object.prototype`, `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`.

And it's a fast way to know if an object has some property. I mean, if `obj.foo` can return e.g. `"bar"` even if the `foo` property is inherited, it makes sense to be able to know if `obj` has that `foo` property or not beforehand, either own or inherited.

Sure, if we only had HasOwnProperty, we could (usually) keep calling [[GetPrototypeOf]] until the end of the chain, and check each object. But that would be tedious to code, probably slower than a native `in`, and not possible before ES5.

Moreover, there is a fundamental difference. The `in` operator uses the [[HasProperty]] internal method, while HasOwnProperty uses [[GetOwnProperty]]. Iterating [[GetOwnProperty]] and [[GetPrototypeOf]] may produce a different result than [[HasProperty]] for non-ordinary objects.

So yes: the `in` operator is useful when you want to call the internal [[HasProperty]] method of an object. In fact, apart from `Reflect.has`, it is the only proper way to do that.

```js
var p = new Proxy({}, {has: function() {
  console.log('Hooray!');
  return true;
}});
p.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // :(
'foo' in p; // Hooray! :)
```

Answer (score 4):

You answer your own question.
`in` is good when you want to search in prototype chain as well.

Comment: I'm looking for specific use cases, like in amdouglas's answer.